# Get textbox input values in JS function on button click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get textbox inputs in my JS function on the click of a button. For some reason my console.log does not show the textbox inputs. How do I accomplish this?

Index.php:

```
  <input placeholder="Name" type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />
  <input placeholder="Password" type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
  <button id="testAJAX" onclick="Utilities.loadSavedGames()">Load Game</button>
```

js/utilties.js

```
var Utilities = {
    loadSavedGames : function () {

    var username = document.getElementById('username').value,
        password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    console.log(username + ", " + password); //null, blank
```

Comment: `console.log` in code or `log`

Comment: Works fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dtyr90p2/)**

Comment: It looks OK. Can you post the full text of php and js file somewhere, so we can find a problem in another part.

Comment: @Tushar sorry that was a typo

Comment: @Growler, kindly make sure that same id is not being used on the same page. Try this code in the browser console: `$('[id=username]').length` and `$('[id=password]').length`, and let me know

Comment: @Arvind that was it. I had a register and a login form on the same page with 2 `username` and `password` id's allocated. Oops! Post as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have elements with duplicate ids on the same page.
Try this code in the browser console: `$('[id=username]').length` and `$('[id=password]').length`. If the count is > 1, you have multiple elements with same id.

Answer (score 0):

Put console.log instead of log and also make utilities as global object.
    I mean remove var.

```
   Utilities = {
    loadSavedGames : function () {

       var username = document.getElementById('username').value,
        password = document.getElementById('password').value;
       console.log(username + ", " + password); 
      }
     }
```

Comment: Utilities should be declared. Isn't it?

Comment: I do not see how this solves the problem. Furthermore, removing the `var` from `Utilities` will cause a run-time error in at least some environments. Suggest deleting this answer.